# Where all the core PHP functions are stored in XAMPP on a computer?

Tags: php, xampp

I am using XAMPP and I just want to know while installing XAMPP what type of file, PHP adds into a computer. Is it `.bin` or `.exe` file only or some other file are it's `.bin` file that contains all the functions like in C++ we make a `.h` file in C++

Where is the body of all core PHP functions declared and how—and where—are all functions stored exactly in XAMPP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XAMPP contains a full release of PHP in the PHP sub-directory, the file that is processed is either:

- `php-win.exe`
- `php-cgi.exe`
- `php.exe`

Comment: @superUser - The functions are compiled in to the above applications and scripts run against them.

If you want a list of the core functions, the best place to look is on the PHP  official manual website located at http://www.php.net/manual/en/